# Convert a string ddmmyyyyhhmi into yyyy-mm-dd in SQL server

Tags: sql, casting, substring

how can I convert a string `ddmmyyyyhhmi` into `yyyy-mm-dd`?

A string `210420161701` (a `varchar`) into `2016-04-21` (a `datetime` data type).

I tried a combination of sub-string, cast, convert but can't seem to make it work.

Please kindly help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 2 lines are just setting up the variable, but the following works (as long as the format is always the same). You may also need to make sure the date format of your SQL installation is correct (SET DATEFORMAT). You can also change the datatype from date to datetime if required.

```
DECLARE @Date Varchar(100) = '210420161701'

DECLARE @DateVariable date

SELECT @DateVariable = SUBSTRING(@date,5,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@date,3,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@date,1,2)

SELECT @DateVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),'210420161701',103),5,4)+ '-'+
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),'210420161701',103),3,2)+'-'+
SUBSTRING(convert(varchar(10),'210420161701',103),1,2)
```